# XSL compilation error, mlink should end with ';'

Tags: xslt

I have an XSL template :

```
<xsl:template name="Url">
  <xsl:param name="Code"></xsl:param>
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$Code = '1'">http://example.com/service/info.do?cid=2136&mlink=5058,10807990,cs_service&clink=10807990</xsl:when>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

When I am running this template, I am getting the below error. Can some one please let me know how could I resolve it?

> [Fatal Error] :149:102: The reference to entity "mlink" must end with the ';' delimiter.
>   Compiler warnings:
>    WARNING:  'org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl: Property 'http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/property/accessExternalDTD' is not recognized.'
>    WARNING:  'org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl: Property 'http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/property/accessExternalDTD' is not recognized.'
>   ERROR:  'Could not compile stylesheet'
>   FATAL ERROR:  'The reference to entity "mlink" must end with the ';' delimiter.'

Answer (score 1):

You have to escape the ampersands(& to `&amp;`) that appear in the text for your URL

```
<xsl:template name="Url">
  <xsl:param name="Code"></xsl:param>
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$Code = '1'">http://example.com/service/info.do?cid=2136&amp;mlink=5058,10807990,cs_service&amp;clink=10807990</xsl:when>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```